# Creating a Ternary Relationship

Tags: powerdesigner, mysql-5.0

How can I make ternary relationship using power designer?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you cannot.
But you can represent the same concept.

Assuming you trying to do that in the Conceptual Data Model, it depends of the Notation you are using (under `Tools > Models Options`).

With Entity/Relationship, it looks like you cannot do it.

With Merise, you create an Association with links toward the 3 entities.

With IDEF1X, you create an Entity with dependent relationships toward the 3 entities.